# Regular Expression to get all characters before "-"

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How can I get the string before the character `"-"` using regular expressions?

For example, I have `"text-1"` and I want to return `"text"`.

Comment: You can use substring in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

So I see many possibilities to achieve this.

```
string text = "Foobar-test";
```

1. Regex Match everything till the first "-"

   ```
   Match result = Regex.Match(text, @"^.*?(?=-)");
   ```

   - `^` match from the start of the string
   - `.*?` match any character (`.`), zero or more times (`*`) but as less as possible (`?`)
   - `(?=-)` till the next character is a "-" (this is a positive look ahead)
2. Regex Match anything that is not a "-" from the start of the string

   ```
   Match result2 = Regex.Match(text, @"^[^-]*");
   ```

   - `[^-]*` matches any character that is not a "-" zero or more times
3. Regex Match anything that is not a "-" from the start of the string till a "-"

   ```
   Match result21 = Regex.Match(text, @"^([^-]*)-");
   ```

   Will only match if there is a dash in the string, but the result is then found in capture group 1.
4. Split on "-"

   ```
   string[] result3 = text.Split('-');
   ```

   Result is an Array the part before the first "-" is the first item in the Array
5. Substring till the first "-"

   ```
   string result4 = text.Substring(0, text.IndexOf("-"));
   ```

   Get the substring from text from the start till the first occurrence of "-" (`text.IndexOf("-")`)

You get then all the results (all the same) with this

```
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.WriteLine(result2);
Console.WriteLine(result21.Groups[1]);
Console.WriteLine(result3[0]);
Console.WriteLine(result4);
```

I would prefer the first method.

You need to think also about the behavior, when there is no dash in the string. The fourth method will throw an exception in that case, because `text.IndexOf("-")` will be `-1`. Method 1  and 2.1 will return nothing and method 2 and 3 will return the complete string.

Comment: What regex can I write to get only 02 out of "10.02 - LIQUOR"

Answer (score 19):

Here is my suggestion - it's quite simple as that:

```
[^-]*
```

Comment: Simple. Love it.

Answer (score 7):

This is something like the regular expression you need:

```
([^-]*)-
```

Quick tests in JavaScript:

```
/([^-]*)-/.exec('text-1')[1] // 'text'

/([^-]*)-/.exec('foo-bar-1')[1] // 'foo'

/([^-]*)-/.exec('-1')[1] // ''

/([^-]*)-/.exec('quux')[1] // explodes
```

Comment: While C# and JS have similar regex syntaxes, they're not all the same. It's not wise to use JavaScript to test regular expressions of any other flavor...

Answer (score 5):

I dont think you need regex to achieve this. I would look at the [SubString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) method along with the [indexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) method. If you need more help, add a comment showing what you have attempted and I will offer more help.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use another non-regex based method. Someone gave the suggestion of using Substring, but you could also use Split:

```
string testString = "my-string";
string[] splitString = testString.Split("-");
string resultingString = splitString[0]; //my
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms228388%28v=VS.80%29.aspx for another good example.

Comment: A few less lines.. 

string resultString = "my-string".Split('-')[0];

Answer (score 2):

Find all word and space characters up to and including a -

```
^[\w ]+-
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want use RegEx in .NET,

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"^([\w]+)(\-)*");
var match = rx.Match("thisis-thefirst");
var text = match.Groups[1].Value;
Assert.AreEqual("thisis", text);
```