# Extract text before _ in a string using regex

Tags: regex

I have some large number of strings which starts like `DD_filename`.

How can I extract the characters before `_` using regular expression.

I tried learning using [from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) and in that it is given `a.b` will retrieve characters starting from `a` and ending on `b`

I tried similarly `^._` but it is not working for me.

Comment: You can use a regex... but it seems more likely splitting it would just be easier & efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^._` will only match one character before `_`. Try this pattern:

```
^.*?(?=_)
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and `^.*(?=_)`? Also, in case there are multiple underscores, would it be better to use `[^_]*` or `.*?` instead of `.*`?

Comment: I cannot imagine a single situation in which a lookbehind is necessary for a zero-width assertion.

Answer (score 5):

Starting from the beginning of the string, capture all non-underscore characters:

```
"^[^_]*"
```

The first `^` (caret) character means that the match starts from the beginning of the string.  The brackets allow you to define a set of possible characters (character class). The second `^` character means "not".  So the character class is "not underscore".  The star means "zero or more".  So in plain English: "match from the start of the string zero or more non underscore characters".

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like

```
.*?(?=_)
```

`.` matches any character and `*?` is a [reluctant quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). `(?=_)` is a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to ensure our match is followed by an `_`.

If you want to only extract characters that occur at the *beginning* of a string you can add the `^` anchor: `^.*?(?=_)`. `^` matches the position before the first character in the string.

Answer (score 2):

Just capture all characters that are not an underscore:

```
"[^_]*"
```

Comment: What this means, in short is "*any character that isn't an underscore (`^` means "not" when in brackets) repeated 0 or more times (that's the `*`)*.

Answer (score 2):

[Regular Expression to get all characters before "-"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224270/regular-expression-to-get-all-characters-before)

Check out @stema's answer. He gives four ways to do this, but the first is probably the best.

```
Match result = Regex.Match(text, @"^.*?(?=-)");

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Don't forget that if you realize after posting that another answer (that's better or the same) has already been posted, there's no cost to deleting your post in order to avoid cluttering questions with answers that don't add anything.