# Retrieve text before specific string Python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to retrieve everything before a specific string in a text file using regex in Python.
For example with the line

```
text = 'What I want is a red car'
```

I would like to retrieve everything that is before "a red car", that is:

```
result = 'What I want is'
```

The whole string "a red car" is important, not only "red" or "car" separately!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? What did you try?

Comment: Actually, this is something you could easily google yourself...

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572362/get-a-string-after-a-specific-substring/12572391#12572391?

Comment: Yes I tried:
found = re.search('(.+?)A red car', text)

It works if I put only "car" or "red" but not when I use the entire string

Comment: `The whole string "a red car" is important,....` but `I would like to retrieve everything that is before "a red car"`

Comment: @JoranBeasley Still a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212936/extract-text-before-in-a-string-using-regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to use a regex for this :

```
regex = re.compile('(?P<before_red_car>.+) a red car')
regex.search("What i want is a red car").group('before_red_car')
```

If you don't want to name your group :

```
regex = re.compile('(.+)a red car')
regex.search("What i want is a red car").group(1)
```

If you need to catch everything including newlines, add the `re.DOTALL` flag.

However, doing

```
text = 'What I want is a red car'
text.split('a red car')[0]
```

Or even :

```
text = 'What I want is a red car'
text.replace('a red car', '')
```

Work too, and are arguably easier to understand.
They are also twice faster :

```
timeit.timeit(lambda: text.split('a red car')[0])
0.5350678942020507

timeit.timeit(lambda: text.replace('a red car', ''))
0.5115460171814448

timeit.timeit(lambda: regex.search("What i want is a red car").group(1))
1.123993800741033 

# Without re.compile()
timeit.timeit(lambda: re.search('(.+)a red car', text).group(1))
1.94518623436079
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
strIn = 'What I want is a red car'
searchStr = 'a red car'
print(strIn[:strIn.find(searchStr)])
```

Answer (score -2):

This might help

```
text = 'What I want is a red car'
print(text[0:13])
```

Comment: And what happens if the text is then changed to `What you want is a red car`?

Comment: you mean  that text = 'What you want is a red card?'

Comment: Exactly that, you will end up returning `What you want`... My point being, that this solution is not dynamic or flexible. Also, I just tested the above and it returns `What I want i`, which doesn't seem like what the OP wants

Comment: yeah your right. But in the question he has not mentioned about any situation like that. Plus he himself is declaring the string text. That's why i came up with this soln.