# How to find word in string with keyword

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on a project where i need to Iterate through every line in a txt file and find where its says .csproj and get the name of the csproj

C:\DataTypes\Nameofthecsproj.csproj this is what it looks like in txt file
so i need to remove "C:\Datetypes\ until i only have: Nameofthecsproj.csproj

```
  foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(FILEPATH))
            {
                if (line.Contains(".csproj"))
                {
                    Match result = Regex.Match(line, @"^.*?(?=csproj)");

                }
            }
```

I just need a way to filter out the rest until i only have Nameofthecsproj.csproj

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224270/regular-expression-to-get-all-characters-before

Comment: follow this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709821/find-text-in-string-with-c-sharp

Comment: You should use 'EndsWith()', use a regex as James Gould proposed or maybe String split (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split)

Comment: The problem is, every new line the name of the csproj is different, i need to kinda loop backwards and get the name

Comment: Using ```Contains``` to check the file extensions is not a good idea, use [Path.GetExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?view=net-6.0) function to check file extension

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove file extension from a file name string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356205/remove-file-extension-from-a-file-name-string)

Answer (score 1):

refer : [Find text in string with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709821/find-text-in-string-with-c-sharp)
Use this method:

```cs
public static string getBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd)
{
    if (strSource.Contains(strStart) && strSource.Contains(strEnd))
    {
        int Start, End;
        Start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, 0) + strStart.Length;
        End = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);
        return strSource.Substring(Start, End - Start);
    }
   return "";
}
```

How to use it:

```cs
string source = "This is an example string and my data is here";
string data = getBetween(source, "my", "is");
```

Comment: You just use the code of other user: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709821/find-text-in-string-with-c-sharp. This is duplicated questions and answer.