# Regex to get all characters AFTER first comma

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a regex pattern to extract some names that apprear in a string after the first comma (David Peter Richard) below.

Example string:
PALMER, David Peter Richard

I came across [this thread that successfully extracts the name before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224270/regular-expression-to-get-all-characters-before), but require all the names after the comma.

I've tried to modify the ^.*?(?=,), but not having any joy. Needs to be JavaScript Regex and capture groups are not supported in the platform i'm using (Bubble)

Any help appreciated, thanks a lot!

I tried this: (?<=,)[^,]+

Which seems to work on Desktop, however on a wrapped mobile app, it doesn't seem to work.

Similarly for the Name before, I was using ^[^,]+ and experiencing the same issue, but when I use the pattern in the ^.*?(?=,) it works fine.

So now I just need the pattern to be adjusted for the names after.

Comment: does your string ends with the name you want to extract or there is expression after?

Comment: I need to extract both and place them in separate fields. So:

First extract the Surname that is always before the comma.
Second extract all the Names (could be 1 or more) that is always after the comma.

Both to exclude the comma.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On JavaScript, I would suggest a simple string split:

```js
var input = "PALMER, David Peter Richard";
var names = input.split(/,\s*/);
console.log(names);
```

Comment: The trick here is that I have two separate fields i need to output the name before the comma and a separate one for the names after the comma, so need two patterns to extract each

Comment: Thanks again Tim.. The reason i ask for two separate queries is that they need to be entered separately in different places. So the first pattern (before the comma) in one place and the second (after the comma) in a different place. So really all i'm left to solve is the 'after the comma' pattern as the 'before the pattern' that i have is working fine:    ^.*?(?=,),  Appreciate your input. thanks

Comment: Use: `^[^,]+` for the first portion and `(?<=, ).*` for the second portion.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this regex for the after comma string:

```
(?<=,\s)(.*)$
```

hope this helps.

Comment: This seems to extract it with the comma, is there a way to exclude the comma? Thanks